# Can I do everything with react.js just using CDN libraries, without any installations at all ?

Tags: reactjs, cdn

Can I do everything with react.js just using CDN libraries, without any installations at all ?

For example can I always use JavaScript libraries like this?

```
<script src="https://cdn/X.js"></script>

const X = window.X;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is absolutely possible, and there are loads of resources. It's no different from building any other JS application on a given framework:

- http://jamesknelson.com/learn-raw-react-no-jsx-flux-es6-webpack/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html
- https://medium.com/@clmyles/react-without-npm-babel-or-webpack-1e9a6049714
- https://twitter.com/JedWatson/status/927445144453857280

**BUT...** there's a lot to be said for the current React development ecosystem that makes the build tooling (i.e. Babel, Webpack, ESLint, Prettier, Glamorous, etc.) very enticing. And the use of JSX is an incredible advantage, for the sake of quick prototyping alone, which you will not be able to utilize if you can't build. All in all, building out a **comfortable, custom developmen**t environment can take time and be pain, however the ROI is tangible. Which is why I'd suggest **CRA**:

- https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

No,not a good idea.Your application performance drops.You will not able to use npm module features,if you don't install NPM. Make use of [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) or [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) which ships some great features and easy to setup.